# If $U \subset V$ are vectors spaces, then $V = U \oplus X$ for some vector space

Tags: linear-algebra

Is it true that if $U \subset V$ are vectors spaces, one can always find a vector space $X \subset V $ so that $V = U \oplus X$?

I know this it true when $V$ is finite dimensional, but is it true also in the infinite dimension case?

Thanks.